# Setting baseUrl for img tag in HTML fragment

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom

I have a page hosted on `domain1` from which I retrieve, with an ajax call, an HTML fragment which include some  tags. These tags have a relative `src` URL and I want to set, for these tag only, a base URL pointing to another domain, say `domain2`.

Here's an example: I have a String `HTMLData` with the following value:

```
'<p> Foo </p> \
<img alt = "Image 1" src = "/relativepath/To/Image1"> \
<div class = "someDiv"> \
    <img alt = "Image 2" src = "/relativepath/To/Image2"> \
</div>'
```

I want to add to my page something like:

```
'<p> Foo </p> \
<img alt = "Image 1" src = "http://domain2/relativepath/To/Image1"> \
<div class = "someDiv"> \
    <img alt = "Image 2" src = "http://domain2/relativepath/To/Image2"> \
</div>'
```

Of course, I have no idea of the exact structure of the fragment, and I will probably want to extend it to other embedded object tags.

Here is what I have written so far:

```
function setBaseURLandConstructDiv (HTMLData) {
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    container.innerHTML = HTMLData;
    var images = container.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var image = 0;image<images.length;image++) {
        if (images[image].src) {
            images[image].src = 'http://domain2'+ images[image].getAttribute('src');
        }
    }
    return container.innerHTML;
}
```

It works, but it doesn't seems right to me. In particular, at the line `container.innerHTML = HTMLData`, the browser make an unnecessary request to `http://domain1/relativepath/To/Image1`, before making the (correct) call to `http://domain2/relativepath/To/Image1` at the line  `images[image].src = 'http://domain2'+ images[image].getAttribute('src');`

So is there another method to modify the `src` attributes? (Or to locally set a base Url)

Comment: from where comes the `HTMLData` parameter?

Comment: `HTMLData` is a String, coming (in my usecase) from an ajax call

Comment: Added specific example

Answer (score 0):

what happens when you use HTMLData to get the images for you array?
You could first change the HTMLData and then assign it to the container.

Comment: HTML data is a string, not a node. I don't know how to convert it to a node without using en existing Node and its innerHTML property

Comment: it doesn't have to be a node, you can just split the string on the image tags and then replace the soucre of each one.